# continuous fuction on boundary of two simplex is nullhomotopic

Tags: algebraic-topology, homology-cohomology

This is part of the Hurwitz theorem

Let $f:\Delta^2\to X$ is a continuous function, where $\Delta^2$ is standard 2 simplex.Define $d_0:[0,1]\to \Delta^2$ as the affine map, with $d_0(0)=e_1,d_0(1)=e_2$ ,simlarly, $d_1(0)=e_0,d_1(1)=e_2$,$d_2(0)=e_0,d_2(1)=e_1$ and finally define $f_i=fdi$

Prove that $(f_0\ast(f_1)^{-1})\ast f_2$ is nullhomotopic rel{$0,1$} ,where $\ast$ is the usaual group operator for path

Here is some of my idea:
it is enough to show there is a homotopy F:$(f_0\ast(f_1)^{-1})\ast f_2 \simeq k$, where $k(x)=f_0(e_1)$. If X is $\Bbb R^n$,then we can define$F(x,t)=t(f_0\ast(f_1)^{-1})\ast f_2)(x)+(1-t)k(x)$.But how can we do for arbitrary topological space?

Some people will say this is that a continuous map on the boundary of simplex is homopotic to contant map.

Thanks in advanced.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fortunately, I get the answer, the reason is as follows.
In fact, we just think the $[e_0,e_2]$ is homotopic to the path go along $[e_0,e_1]$ and $[e_1,e_2]$,which is  true by line homotopy, Next, compose with $f$, we the the "very close homotopy, again, by operating the operation $*$, we get $k$ is homotopic to $f_0*f_1^{-1}*f_2$, where $k(x)=f_2(e_0)$ for all $x$. Thus,we get it is nullhomotopic. Thus, by this step, we can drive the kernel of the Hurewicz homomorphism is $\pi(X,x_0)^{'}$, which is a beautiful isomorphism.